# iOS) value of timeIntervalSince70 is fixed when i approach at the level of second

Tags: ios, timer, nsdate

I want to update label that shows time left between 2 nsdates everysecond.

my code is below :

```
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
double diff = [campaignDate timeIntervalSince1970] - [nowDate timeIntervalSince1970];

int diff_day = diff/60/60/24 - 1; 
int diff_hour = ((int)diff/60/60)%24;
int diff_min = ((int)diff/60)%60;
int diff_sec = ((int)diff/60/60)%60;
```

When i logged diff_sec , it always shows me 49
day,hour and min value is printed in working order

why does that diff_sec make a problem? is there any solution ?

Comment: And i already checked that double diff value is changed every second at the level of millesecond

Comment: format of 2 nsdates is same

Comment: Instead of `timeIntervalSince1970` on each date use 
`timeIntervalSinceNow`. `NSTimeInterval diff = -[campaignDate timeIntervalSinceNow];`

Comment: @Zaph thank you but i checked that value is changed everysecond so i want to know why that second value is fixed.

Comment: @Zaph and the result is the same when i use 'timeIntervalSinceDate:'

Comment: I suspect it is to do with the typecast. shouldn't the cast be outside the division so as not to lose precision? like ((int)(diff/60/60))%60

Comment: My comment was not an answer, just simpler code.

Comment: @Bamsworld I already did it but doesn't work anyway, actually I think it is very hard to find out the reason.

Comment: While the answer using NSCalendar and NSDateComponents is an excellent method it does not really answer the question: what is wrong with the code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use NSDateComponents to get the number of days/hours/minutes/seconds between two days.

Then you can get the remaing time like this:

```
NSDate *fromDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *toDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:12345];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

NSLog(@"Event in %@ days, %@:%@:%@", @(difference.day), @(difference.hour), @(difference.minute), @(difference.second));
```

Comment: you made it thank you! can you explain why my code is in problem?

Comment: Interesting, converting the integers to `NSNumbers` only to use `%@` instead of just using %i as in the answer by @N J Gadhiya.

Comment: LKM: Maybe in the case of seconds it might be just ((int)diff)%60? But I'm not sure. I prefer using the NSDateComponents. You can check that out on NSHipster site: http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/ and http://nshipster.com/nscalendar-additions/

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSCalendar`

```
NSDate *dateA;
NSDate *dateB;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:dateA
                                             toDate:dateB
                                            options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference in date components: %i/%i/%i", components.day, components.month, components.year);
```

Comment: The question is day, hour, minute, seconds not day, month, year.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in calculating diff_sec, the divisions by 60 are incorrect because `diff` is already in seconds.

Incorrect code:

```
int diff_sec = ((int)diff/60/60)%60;
```

Correct code

```
int diff_sec = ((int)diff)%60;
```